# Update Socrata dataset metadata through API

Tags: metadata, socrata, soda

According to [Socrata's "Publisher Guide"](https://dev.socrata.com/publishers/):

> The Publisher API allows you to programatically:
>
> - Add, update, and delete records within a Socrata dataset
> - Maintain dataset metadata and privacy settings

But I can't see anywhere in the [API docs](https://dev.socrata.com/docs/endpoints.html) that explains how to do this. It's all about creating, updating or removing individual rows - nothing to do with dataset metadata.

For instance - how do you add a tag to an existing dataset, using the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry if that statement is a little misleading. Metadata update is available officially through the [`soda-java`](https://github.com/socrata/soda-java#update-dataset-metadata) library and unofficially through [`sodapy`](https://github.com/xmunoz/sodapy).

To understand properly, you're looking to update the set of tags programmatically on a set of datasets, and if I've read your profile correctly, it looks like you'll have access to the Socrata platform as a data publisher. Correct?

Comment: Yes, correct. In this particular instance, I want to add a tag to a bunch of datasets based on a heuristic, then later remove them. Judging from the [sodaypy code](https://github.com/xmunoz/sodapy/blob/master/sodapy/__init__.py#L130), the answer is just to do a `PUT` on the whole dataset. Still not really clear how to distinguish between replacing the data and the metadata.

Comment: The {{PUT}} is on the dataset metadata, not on the dataset itself. Something like this would update the tags: `PUT /api/views/$id.json { "tags": ["foo", "bar", "bang"] }`

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I'm not the only one asking! https://github.com/xmunoz/sodapy/issues/22

Comment: Yep, that issue thread should provide you enough to get started. Hopefully that works until we have more official documentation for you.